# mysql Importing csv data to table

Tags: mysql, csv, import

I have a csv value file I populated with the data I want to import to a mysql table using php my admin.

When importing the csv file I get this error message "Invalid column count in CSV input on line 11."

The table has this 6 columns.

This is the text on line 11 (I used "+" as separator of columns):

```
bue+rio+Full day all inclusive fly fishing dorado y tararira en San Pedro+buerio160+<a href='bue1_10.php#toursbue' title ='click for photos and detailed information about Dorado & Tararira (dogfish) Fly Fishing all inclusive Experience'>Dorado & Tararira (dogfish) Fly Fishing all inclusive Experience</a> (full day).+<b><a href='bue1_10.php#toursbue' title ='click for photos and detailed information about Dorado & Tararira (dogfish) Fly Fishing all inclusive Experience'>Dorado & Tararira (dogfish) Fly Fishing all inclusive Experience</a></b>.<br>Enjoy the incomparable experience of fly fishing Dorado and Tararira (dogfish), surrounded by a unique landscape.<br>Located very close to Buenos Aires city (a 1-hour-and-a-half drive), San Pedro consists of a delta where hundreds of streams and channels get together, giving home to these species, so desired by fly fishermen. This tour is done in private basis (full day).
```

As you can see there are 5 "+" signs which delimit the 6 columns. I anyway get the invalid column count error.

I have been trying many different things to solve this more more than 2 hours, so I'm feeling very frustraded (and an idiot!) . Hope that someone can enlighten my on what I'm doing wrong.
I have the complete csv file if you need it.

Thanks a ton!

Fred

Comment: If you're using `+` to separate the columns this is not a _comma_ separated value file.

Answer (score 0):

I only count 4 '+' on line 11 meaning there would be 5 columns in the csv on that line, whereas your table has 6 columns

```
bue
+
rio
+
Full day all inclusive fly fishing dorado y tararira en San Pedro+buerio160
+
<a href='bue1_10.php#toursbue' title ='click for photos and detailed information about      Dorado & Tararira (dogfish) Fly Fishing all inclusive Experience'>Dorado & Tararira (dogfish) Fly Fishing all inclusive Experience</a> (full day).
+
<b><a href='bue1_10.php#toursbue' title ='click for photos and detailed information    about Dorado & Tararira (dogfish) Fly Fishing all inclusive Experience'>Dorado & Tararira (dogfish) Fly Fishing all inclusive Experience</a></b>.<br>Enjoy the incomparable experience of fly fishing Dorado and Tararira (dogfish), surrounded by a unique landscape.<br>Located very close to Buenos Aires city (a 1-hour-and-a-half drive), San Pedro consists of a delta where hundreds of streams and channels get together, giving home to these species, so desired by fly fishermen. This tour is done in private basis (full day).
```